# How to ping when behind a proxy?

Tags: linux, command-line, proxy, ping, http-proxy

I am using an HTTP proxy server to connect to the internet.

Because of that my pings are not working

```
ping www.google.com
```

says Unreachable Host

**How can I configure `ping` to use the HTTP proxy?**

Comment: It may be helpful to know what setup you are using?  Is this a linux server with squid and iptables for example?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

In general you can't. `ping` needs a direct network connection on the IP level to do its work. A proxy works on a higher layer of the [TCP/IP network model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcp/ip), where there is no direct access to the IP protocol.

You would need to somehow circumvent the proxy (change firewall settings, use a VPN, ...). Whether this is possible (and allowed) depends on your network configuration, but it's probably not possible.

As a workaround, there are many web-based ping services available (search for "web-based ping"). These will work.

Comment: Web-based pings cannot be used to test the latency of my own connection, as they are initiated from the server. Maybe some implementation of ping in java that runs in the browser.

Comment: While the ICMP protocol operates on ISO/OSI layer 3, the `ping` utility operates on layer 7. To quote my CS teacher, ping is a 3-7 hybrid. It may well be possible that the layer 7 part is capable of proxy handling. This would explain why my [answer to this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/428408/can-not-ping-google-using-proxy/428414) works (at least for me).

Comment: @the_Seppi: Interesting, I've never heard of `ping` being layer 7. Do you have any pointers for further reading?

Answer (score 10):

You may try this,But first you have to install curl.

```
http_proxy=http://<proxy_username>:<proxy_password>@<your_proxy_server>:<your_proxy_port>  curl -I http://google.com/
```

Comment: this is not PING.

Comment: or you can use `curl -x 'http://<proxy_username>:<proxy_password>@<your_proxy_server>:<your_proxy_port>'`

Comment: @törzsmókus: But it is likely a good answer to the source of the question ... to test, if some server is available and working!

Comment: The question was, _How can I configure ping to use the HTTP proxy?_ This post by @Ishant Mrinal does not answer that. If someone asks a question _[How] to test, if some server is available and working [from behind a proxy?]_, feel free to add this answer, and also link to it in the comments of this question.

Comment: @törzsmókus - You are correct in that the answer does not address strictly the question. It may be the case that the OP (or other readers searching for a similar idea, as myself) asks this while not being specifically interested in using ping, but in using it only as a quick way to test if a given PC is reaching the outside network (as another use, besides the comment by Andreas Dietrich).
I found this answer **useful** (the main idea behind SO), and so did at least other 8 users.

Answer (score 6):

As others noted, `ping` doesn't work through proxy.

But you can use utility `httping` for that. It sends a HEAD request (by default) to a web server and measures the time it took to get a response.

Example:

```
httping -x 192.68.1.12:1080 -g http://google.com
```

Example output:

```
➜  ~ httping -g http://google.com -c 3
PING google.com:80 (/):
connected to 64.233.165.113:80 (313 bytes), seq=0 time= 38.49 ms 
connected to 64.233.165.101:80 (313 bytes), seq=1 time= 66.94 ms 
connected to 64.233.165.100:80 (313 bytes), seq=2 time= 40.79 ms 
--- http://google.com/ ping statistics ---
3 connects, 3 ok, 0.00% failed, time 3162ms
round-trip min/avg/max = 38.5/48.7/66.9 ms
```

Where:

- `-x` - Address of a proxy server, port is optional
- `-g` - URL to send
  a request to

Other useful options:

- `-5` - Use SOCKS5. Should be put after the `-x` option, i.e.:

  ```
  httping -x localhost:1080 -5 -g http://google.com
  ```
- `-c` - How many probes to send before exiting. Infinite by default.
- `-G` - Do a GET request instead of a HEAD request. That means that also full page/file will be transferred. Note that in this case you're no longer measuring the latency! Useful for testing actual websites.

Be noticed that the time measured also includes the latency introduced by the proxy server itself.

---

The utility is available through a number of repositories for different OS'es and Linux distros:

Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt install httping
```

Alpine:

```
sudo apk add httping
```

macOS with Homebrew:

```
brew install httping
```

---

As another example, I used `httping` to estimate latency of my connection to Tor network through Tor proxy:

```
httping -x localhost:9050 -5 -g http://google.com
```

The only option I wish `httping` had is the ability to ask SOCKS5 proxy for domain name resolution, instead of doing it on its own, which is a more secure way with Tor.

---

Here is a link to the author's website:

https://www.vanheusden.com/httping/

Comment: This is not ping. Ping works on low level to get you faster responses. If you are using httping, then as it works with HEAD requests, there will be much speed loss depending on server's ability to serve requests, PHP, Node.js whatever. Example: I am getting a ping of less than 10ms for Google DNS 8.8.8.8, but I am getting ping of 120ms via httping for https://google.com/ even when website is CDN enabled.

Comment: @Rehmat That's literally the third sentence in my answer. Since `ping` is typically used to figure out if one can reach a specific server (or, often, any server at all) through a specific connection, `httping` is a good enough replacement for situations where `ping` won't do.

Answer (score 1):

Following : **Bogdan Kondratov** answer, here is a **free http-ping utility for windows**

- Download at : https://www.coretechnologies.com/products/http-ping/
- Usage behind a proxy ( e.g company proxy )

```
 http-ping -p http://142.4.15.25:3128 https://www.coretechnologies.com
```