# Unable to access internet from Windows Command Processor

Tags: windows-7, networking, command-line, firewall

I am unable to access internet from the `Windows Command Processor`. Below is the output on doing a simple ping:

```
C:\Users\vivekkumar>ping www.stackexchange.com

Pinging www.stackexchange.com [198.252.206.16] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 198.252.206.16:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

I checked my firewall settings and found that `Windows Command Processor` was missing from the list of programs that are allowed to communicate through the Windows Firewall. So, I added it. Also, restarted the firewall service. However, I still get the same issue.

The firewall rules corresponding to `cmd.exe` now are:

```
Rule Name:                            Windows Command Processor
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Enabled:                              Yes
Direction:                            In
Profiles:                             Domain,Private,Public
Grouping:                             
LocalIP:                              Any
RemoteIP:                             Any
Protocol:                             TCP
LocalPort:                            Any
RemotePort:                           Any
Edge traversal:                       Yes
Action:                               Allow
```

There is another similar rule for UDP. Also, I am able to ping computers on my local network and my internet is working fine.

What can I do to resolve this issue.

Comment: If you totally disable your firewall, does the issue resolve itself? Are you behind a proxy or anything similar?

Comment: Tried disabling the firewall, it didn't work. As per http://whatismyipaddress.com/proxy-check , yes a Proxy server was detected.

Comment: I found that I was indeed behind a proxy and then I found this - http://superuser.com/questions/175428/how-to-ping-when-behind-a-proxy . So, turns out I can't really use ping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Totally disable your firewall (if safe to do so) is normally a good way to test.

If you are behind a proxy, you can't really get the return.

**Edit**

As per the link in your comments, more details are here: [How to ping when behind a proxy?](https://superuser.com/questions/175428/how-to-ping-when-behind-a-proxy)